# Decorator that supplies arguments to functions

Tags: python, meta-programming

I have assignment to generate argument based decorator I wrote like this.

```
def my_decorator(*deco_args): 
    def wrap(f):
        def wrapped_f(*func_args):
            if len(deco_args) == 1 and len(func_args) ==1:
                return f(func_args[0], deco_args[0])
            elif len(deco_args) == 2 and len(func_args) == 2:
                return f(*(deco_args+func_args))
        return wrapped_f
    return wrap

@my_decorator(2)
def pow(x, y): 
    return x ** y

print pow(4) #=> 16

@my_decorator("/home", "user")
def path(*args):
   return "/".join(args)

print path("videos", "cats.png") #=> "/home/user/videos/cats.png"
```

Is there any better way to do this ?

Comment: What exactly was your assignment? Why does `func_args` sometimes precede `deco_args` and sometimes `func_args` follow `deco_args`? Perhaps you should calculate `2 ** 4` instead of `4 ** 2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think `my_decorator` is a very descriptive name, but maybe that's just part of the assignment.  Also, `f` isn't a very descriptive name for the function you are decorating.

I did my own test:

```
>>> @my_decorator(2)
... def here(*args):
...     print args
... 
>>> here(4, 5)
>>>
```

Do you know why it doesn't print anything?  It's because you have `if` and `elif` in `wrapped_f`, but one argument to `my_decorator` and two arguments to `here` doesn't match either of your conditions, so `wrapped_f` doesn't know what to do.  To be safe, it does not call the function and just returns `None`.  That always happens when you don't tell a function what to return: it returns `None`.  My question is, why do you have those conditions?  I would change that function to:

```
def wrapped_f(*func_args):
    return f(*(deco_args+func_args))
```

---

Your code really has only four lines of reviewable code, so I will just suggest a new (not necessarily better) way:

```
from functools import partial

class MyDecorator:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.args = args
    def __call__(self, func):
        return partial(func, *self.args)
```

[`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) takes a function and any other arguments and returns a callable object that, when called, calls the function with the original arguments and whatever other arguments are given.  Our decorator is called with `2` for my above example, so it sets `self.args` to `(2,)`.  When our `MyDecorator` object is called (with `here` as an argument), the `__call__` method is executed and we return a `partial` object with that function and the arguments we got earlier.  Therefore, when the result is called with more arguments, it calls the function with the arguments originally given to the decorator as well as the arguments being given currently.  You can see that `partial` is very similar to your decorator.  We just needed to make it decorator-compatible.

---

**Edit**: As mentioned by @JoeWallis in the comments, you could still use `partial()` in nested functions similar to yours:

```
def my_decorator(*deco_args):
    def wrap(f):
        return partial(f, *deco_args)
    return wrap
```

Comment: I used that condition because, if you see, in `pow` we are passing 2 arguments, but when call, it passed only one argument. Second argument I passed from decorator argument. Thanks for answer.

Comment: @Lafada: When you pass `2` as an argument, `deco_args` will be `(2,)`.  When you pass `4` later, `func_args` will be `(4,)`.  Consequently, `deco_args + func_args` will be `(2, 4)` and `f(*(deco_args + func_args))` will be `pow(2, 4)`.

Comment: `f` seems like a very reasonable name for a completely generic function.

Comment: @200_success: Reasonable, but not optimal IMO.  I prefer to use names that are unambiguous.  `f` could be used for anything that starts with "f".  I prefer `func`, `function`, `wrapped`, `wrapped_func`, etc.

Comment: @zondo Fair enough, I [find this easier](http://pastebin.com/gCNYi6Ri) to read (Don't want to post an answer), you don't. I'll clean up my other comments

Comment: @JoeWallis: Yes, that does look pretty good.  I have added it to my answer, with proper attribution :)

Answer (score 1):

Please pardon my delay, I just thought I had [something very similar](https://github.com/hemangandhi/derpspace/blob/master/pythons/algorithms/hemanUtils.py#L46) which may help tremendously.

I think I have a much similar implementation except with predicates instead of argument counts and more arbitrariness with the calls of functions.

In terms of my thing, I think yours can be written as follows:

```
def my_decorator(n_args):
    #see the similar thing to understand partial_til_cond's implementation
    #it's a wrapper that raises a TypeError if the second lambda is True,
    #stores previous arguments if the first lambda is True (both for the entire arg list),
    #and calls the wrapped function otherwise.
    return partial_til_cond(lambda x: len(x) < 2 * n_args, 
                            lambda x: len(x) not in [n_args, 2 * n_args])

pow = my_decorator(2)(lambda x,y: x ** y)(2)
path = my_decorator(4)(lambda *files: "/".join(files))("home", "user")
```

`pow` and `path` were written on their own lines to hide the underlying `lambda`s.

Also, your code returns `None` in the cases where there aren't 2 or 4 total arguments. Mine will raise a `TypeError`. Yours seems to only handle two or four arguments while this would take  care of any even number.